# Variation of Kinetic Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

[image]

Question: Which of the following graphs correctly describes the variation of kinetic energy with time of a block when it slides down a smooth inclined plane from rest?

The answer is C but I do not understand why. How do we know if the velocity increases as it slides down the inclined plane?

Comment: If it's on a "smooth" (read: frictionless) inclined plane, how could it _not_ be speeding up?

Comment: It was not initially clear to me that "kinetic friction" (solid to solid, moving) is practically constant with increasing speed, so that there is always an accelerating net force. (The others seemed to take that for granted.) If the friction increased, as air friction would, something like A would be correct; think sky-divers who reach terminal velocity when drag and gravity cancel each other out.

Answer (score 4):

The conserved mechanical energy is:

$E=KE+V=KE+mgh$

where $h$ is the height of the body. As the body slides down due to the acceleration of gravity, the distance travelled would be $d=\tfrac{1}{2}a{{t}^{2}}$, where $a$ is the acceleration caused by the addition of the weight of the body and the vertical reaction force. If $L$ is the length of the inclined plane and $\theta $ the inclination angle, then:

$h=\left( L-d \right)\sin \theta =L\sin \theta -\tfrac{1}{2}a{{t}^{2}}\sin \theta $

Plugging this to the mechanical energy formula and rearranging the terms we get:

$KE=A+B{{t}^{2}}$

where $A=E-mgL\sin \theta $ and $B=\tfrac{1}{2}mga\sin \theta $. Since it is only the energy difference that is of physical importance, we can set the mechanical energy level such that $A=0$. So:

$KE=B{{t}^{2}}$

which is the equation for a convex parabola that crosses the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following free body diagram:

[image]

The net force acting on the body along the surface = $mg \sin x$

Therefore, the net acceleration in that direction is $g \sin x$.
So the velocity of the body at a time t after starting to slide down the inclined plane is $ v = gt \sin x$

So, K.E. (kinetic energy) of the body is $$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2}mg^2t^2 \sin^2 x$$

Hence we conclude that $K.E. \propto t^2$.

The graph of K.E. and t is a parabola. So option C is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Its a graph of $y = {v(t)}^2= kt^2$.

Graph of $x^2$ is:

[graph http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP29252043e2d43bebg8bb000049f405gb0d606d9b?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=62&w=300.&h=190.&cdf=RangeControl](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP29252043e2d43bebg8bb000049f405gb0d606d9b?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=62&w=300.&h=190.&cdf=RangeControl)

When the object moves down from the top, it gets accelerated due to gravititional force or its component so its velocity changes(increases) instant after instant; this means $v^2$ in $\frac{m}{2} v^2$ is a function of time squared. Thus, the variation of KE is a square.

[image: block]

Answer (score -3):

the value of ke increases exponentially as ke = 1/2 x m x v^2, so the v^2 means that the ke value keeps on increasing at a faster rate

Comment: It does not increase "exponentially" but quadratically, since $v_x(t) = a_x t$ and $v_y(t) = a_y t$, where $a_x$ and $a_y$ does not depend on $t$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to display equations and formulae.